# What NuGet package contains System.Data.DataSetExtensions?

Tags: nuget

What NuGet package contains the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly? I have tried installing the EntityFramework package, and that didn't add the reference. I've also tried searching nuget.org for the term DataSet Extensions.

Comment: which entity framework version you installed?

Comment: I installed the most recent EntityFramework version using `Install-Package EntityFramework`. It's 6.1.3.

Comment: And what is the targeted framework of your app?

Comment: The targeted framework of my app is 4.5.

Comment: can you try pointing to 4.0 if there is no specific reason for using 4.5? EF 6 can work with FW 4.0 as well.

Comment: The environment I'm using doesn't allow .NET 4.0 https://dotnetfiddle.net/YaAc6D

Comment: I have never worked on fiddle admittedly, but System.Data.DataSetExtension.dll is standard framework lib. can you simply add reference to that or no?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to add a reference.

Comment: where do you see the requirement(error) to add reference to the said dll?

Comment: I was trying to use `Field<T>(string name)` method. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard .NET Framework assembly, and it's easy to add!

1. Right-click *References* *or* *Dependencies*.
2. Left-click *Add Reference...*.
3. Left-click *Assemblies*.
4. Find *System.Data.DataSetExtensions* and left-click its checkbox.

You should now see something like in the picture below.

[image: Add reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions]

5. Left-click *OK* to finish the wizard.